# SquaredDistance between Vectors in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Iam trying to use the squared distance function in spark but nothing seems to work. I tried Vector.sqdist but getting this error "sqdist is not member of scala.collections......." (but the documentation shows it is a member of [`org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`] which i imported (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)).

```
/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors


object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val v1: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = Vectors.dense(5)
    val v2: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = Vectors.dense(5)

    Vectors.sqdist(v1, v2)
     }
  }
```

My sbt built

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-core_2.10"              % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10"             % "1.1.0"
 )
```

Spark Version: 1.5.0

Do you an alternative of how to use this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scala.collection.immutable.Vector` is not the same as `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`. Moreover `sqdist` is a method of `Vectors` object not `Vector`. Putting this all together:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val v1: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = Vectors.dense(5)
val v2: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = Vectors.dense(5)

Vectors.sqdist(v1, v2)
// Double = 0.0
```

Ignoring above you compile using Spark 1.1.0 (not 1.5.0) and `sqdist` has been introduced in  1.3.0.